# Google Maps API '.pac-item:first' returns with bad formatting

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I am working with grabbing the first item from the possible options on the pac list.  I am finding that the value is always improperly formatted.

**For example when I click the down down I get this:**

```
"Miami, FL, United States"
```

**When I grab it in code I get this:(i.e listen for enter key then select top option)**

```
"MiamiFL, United States"
```

I would like to keep the same format for easy user readability.

Here is the code I have tried, both options result in the same bad formatting.

```
//attempt one
var firstResult = $('.pac-item:first').text();

//attempt two
var firstResult = $('.pac-container .pac-item:first').text();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue, which I sorted out using this fragment of code, I hope it helps you!

```
    var itemFull = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first").text();
    var itemQuery = $(".pac-container .pac-item:first .pac-item-query").text();
    var firstResult = itemQuery + ' ' + itemFull.substring(itemQuery.length);
```